# Get y-value of points along the generated line graph in Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I have two series of data--one consists of (Date, Rating), and the other is a list of events that happened on specific dates.  The ultimate goal is to use the first series of data to construct a line graph to show how the rating has changed over time, which I've done successfully:

[image: line graph]

I now need to plot the second set of data using the dates as x-values (different dates than the first set), but want them to show up on the line--meaning I need to get the y-value of what that date *would* be if it were in the first set.  I hope I explained that clearly; let me know if it's confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot I knew how to do algebra.

```
function getYValue(dataset, date){
    //gets rating estimate for closest surrounding dates using algebraic fun-times
    var point_1, point_2;
    for (j = 0; j < dataset.length; j++){
        if (dataset[j][0] > date) {
            point_1 = dataset[j-1];
            point_2 = dataset[j];
            break;
        }
    }
    var slope = (point_2[1] - point_1[1]) / (point_2[0] - point_1[0]);
    var rating = slope * (date - point_2[0]) + point_2[1];
    return rating;
}
```

Comment: You calculate new points, so let me know what kind of problem you have, because only what you need is add next serie.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're saying--I need the y-values of Series2 to equal the corresponding points on the line generated by the points of Series1.  I do this above by getting the two surrounding points from Series1, finding the equation of the line connecting them, then using that to get the y-value for the new point in Series2.  It works, although there may be an easier way.

Comment: Im afraid that it is a simple way, becasue always you need to iterate over points and calculate it.

Comment: My way works fine; was just wondering if a built-in way already existed.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not build-in.